# How do I iterate through a series of functions in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a very large function that I'm breaking into smaller functions. It currently looks like:

```
def big_function():
    # process1
    # process2
    # process3
    # process4
    # process5
    # process6
    # etc....
```

Once I break down the functions, I'll want to apply them one by one. Rather than calling each function in order, is there a way to iterate through them one by one? Something like:

```
def iterate_through_functions:
    for function in functions:
        # run each process function in order

    def process1():
        # do something
    def process2():
        # do something
    def process3():
        # do something
    def process4():
        # do something
    def process5():
        # do something
    def process6():
        # do something
    def etc....():
        # do something
```

Comment: May be: `functions = [process1, process2, ...]` then iterate...

Comment: I'm confused by this sentence, which sounds like the same thing stated in apposition: "Rather than calling each function in order, is there a way to iterate through them one by one?" Are these not the same things?

Comment: What I mean is that if I have say fifteen functions, I'd simply have to write out each function's name and call it, and it feels like a lot of manual writing which isn't reduced by simply writing them individually as a list. If I dynamically generate the list this works - but how do I iterate those functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the confusion is on how to call the functions while iterating?

```
def function1():
    print 'function1'

def function2():
    print 'function2'

functions = [function1, function2]

for function in functions:
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use locals() to run an arbitrary set of named functions from a list like this:

```
def x():
    print "x"
def y():
    print "y"
def z():
    print "z"

for fxn in ['x','y','z']:
     locals()[fxn]()
```

Using this approach you should be able to develop a configurable process list.

Edit:

This is good if you know the names of the functions. If you just want to run functions you have collected you can simply iterate them off the list.

```
for fxn in [x,y,z]:
   fxn()
```

The reason to use the first approach is that you can build your function list programmatically with a text pattern like run all functions that begin with 'foo_' or 'bar_'. If you're just collecting callbacks use the second approach.

Comment: Is this the best way to iterate the functions per mshsayem's comment?

Answer (score 0):

Mshsayem's comment that you can just create a list of the functions and iterate through that is correct. However, for readability and debugging's sake, you are almost certainly better off just calling each function explicitly, unless you're generating the functions dynamically and you do not know how many of them there will be.